# Loading Facebook ActionScript library in an HTML Adobe AIR app

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript, air

I'm writing an Adobe AIR app using plain HTML which needs to upload photos to Facebook. I don't think Facebook's JavaScript/Connect library includes photo uploading functionality, but their ActionScript library does. However, I'm having trouble loading the ActionScript library into the HTML page.

Adobe's documentation describes [the process of loading ActionScript libraries into HTML AIR apps](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ed9.html), which I tried using the compiled Flash library available [here](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) (specifically, Facebook_library_with_AIRConnect_v3.4_flash.swc). So my page looks something like:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="Facebook_library_with_AIRConnect_v3.4_flash.swc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        // code here...
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div>content here...</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

But when I try to actually create an object, it can't seem to find the class:

```
var fb = new window.runtime.com.facebook.Facebook();
// TypeError: Value  is not a constructor. Cannot be used with new.
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, but I had a couple ideas:

- Is the compiled library file I used the wrong one (do I need a .swf instead of a .swc)?
- If so, do I need to create my own compiled library somehow from the ActionScript source?
- Is the namespace I'm using incorrect? (in addition to com.facebook.Facebook() I tried .Facebook(), .fb.Facebook(), .facebook.Facebook(), etc)
- Should I just give up and try to learn Flex instead?

Any help/insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after a bit more thought I managed to figure it out.

Turns out I *did* need to load a .swf file. The .swc is a container format, so if you change the .swc extension to .zip and unpack it, you get a .swf file (and a couple other files). I included that .swf file instead of the .swc file and things seem to be working now:

```
var fb = new window.runtime.com.facebook.Facebook();
// it works!
```